# Generic title command used to insert a pdf or text specified as key value

Tags: titles, document-classes, class-options, titling

I'm trying to get my own generic title command I can use either to include a pdf file as a title page, is that file exists, or include a text subdivided in keys using the xkeyval package.

My question is to be able to use either `\title[my_pdf_file.pdf]` or `\title[maintitle=My main title, subtitle=My subtitle]` transparently.

The code I have for now in my class file is this one:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%

    % Use bullets in lists instead of large dashes. Must be inside the document scope to work.
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textbullet}

    % Redefine the title commmand

    % makeatletter and makeatother are unneeded in class files.
    %\makeatletter

    % Restrict the commands to the internals of this class file.
    \def\@maintitle{}
    \def\@subtitle{}
    \def\@author{}

    \define@key{title}{maintitle}{%
        \def\@maintitle{%
            \hrule%
            \vspace{0.4cm}
            % We always need to define \par in scope for a font size change, otherwise, if the title is ever longer than a line, it will wrap to the next line with huge characters on a normal baseline.
            {\Huge\textbf{#1}\par}%
            \vspace{0.4cm}%
            \hrule
        }%
    }
    \define@key{title}{subtitle}{%
        \def\@subtitle{%
            \vspace{1.5cm}
            {\Large{#1}\par}%
        }%
    }
    \define@key{title}{author}{%
        \def\@author{%
            {\emph{Author: #1}\par}%
        }%
    }

    % The outer bracket is the renewcommand syntax, the inner one is a group definition avoiding \@author to leak out and be the default in later uses.
    \renewcommand{\title}[1][]{{%

        \IfFileExists{./#1}{%
            \includepdf[pages={1}]{#1}%
        }%
        {%
            \setkeys{title}{#1}            
            \key@ifundefined{#1}{\PackageError{'#1' is not a valid key}}

            \begin{titlepage}
                \begin{center}
                    \renewcommand{\hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}
                    \@maintitle
                    \@subtitle
                    \vfill%
                    \@author
                \end{center}
            \end{titlepage}%
        }
    }}
}
```

The problems I'm experiencing are:

1. when using \title[my_pdf_file.pdf], underscores are interpreted,
   and I don't want to have to escape them manually.
2. when using a
   standard manual title written in text `\title[maintitle=Some
   long\\main title]`, the `\IfFileExists` seems to be interpreted and the
   title is written two times: one unformatted on one page, and another on the next
   page, but that time in the correct format (big letters, centered, with lines above and below that text)
3. I want to get an error risen if I specify a value which isn't a valid readable file, and that value isn't a valid key neither (nor maintitle, subtitle or author). I cannot get `\key@ifundefined{#1}{\PackageError{'#1' is not a valid key}}` working.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're defining the keys at begin document.

Comment: @egreg Indeed you are right. I implemented the whole thing this way, because, before, the document wasn't compiling when I specified the code outside the `AtBeginDocument`. I tested again and this is now compiling. Thanks for the optimization hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions have no easy answer, but I've found a different approach which works and can be of your interest. But first, your questions:

1. I don't know how to properly deal with underscores in filenames using your approach. The general advice is to avoid them (but my proposed approach will allow them)
2. I don't know why that happens, somehow the internals of `\IfFileExists` cause the expansion of its argument (I think it is because the "file" you specify when using `maintitle` etc keywords is not found, and then that filename is parsed again to see if it contains sub-folders).
3. The macro `\key@undefined` is not part of package `keyval`. But you don't need it. Standard behaviour of `keyval` already provides this feature (i.e: to produce a compilation error when a key is specified which was not previously declared)

Admittedly, my previous answers were not very useful. So let's try a different approach.

Why don't you provide the filename of the external pdf as another keyword instead of giving it "directly"? My proposed soultion would be, either:

```
\title[maintitle=My main title, subtitle=My subtitle]
```

or

```
\title[externalpdf=wonderful_title.pdf]
```

Even, you can combine both, so that if the external pdf exists, it is used, but if not, the other keywords are used:

```
\title[externalpdf=wonderful_title.pdf, maintitle=My main title, subtitle=My subtitle]
```

Using this approach, you get as a bonus the unexpected ability to have underscores in the filename.

This is the implementation:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%

    % Use bullets in lists instead of large dashes. Must be inside the document scope to work.
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textbullet}

    % Redefine the title commmand

    % makeatletter and makeatother are unneeded in class files.
    %\makeatletter

    % Restrict the commands to the internals of this class file.
    \def\@maintitle{}
    \def\@subtitle{}
    \def\@author{}
    \def\@filename{}

    \define@key{title}{maintitle}{%
        \def\@maintitle{%
            \hrule%
            \vspace{0.4cm}
            % We always need to define \par in scope for a font size change, otherwise, if the title is ever longer than a line, it will wrap to the next line with huge characters on a normal baseline.
            {\Huge\textbf{#1}\par}%
            \vspace{0.4cm}%
            \hrule
        }%
    }
    \define@key{title}{subtitle}{%
        \def\@subtitle{%
            \vspace{1.5cm}
            {\Large{#1}\par}%
        }%
    }
    \define@key{title}{author}{%
        \def\@author{%
            {\emph{Author: #1}\par}%
        }%
    }

    \define@key{title}{externalfile}{%
        \def\@filename{#1}%
    }


    \renewcommand{\title}[1][]{{%
        \setkeys{title}{#1}
        \IfFileExists{\@filename}{%
            \includepdf[pages={1}]{\@filename}%
        }%
        {%
            \begin{titlepage}
                \begin{center}
                    \renewcommand{\hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}
                    \@maintitle
                    \@subtitle
                    \vfill%
                    \@author
                \end{center}
            \end{titlepage}%
        }
    }}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title[externalfile=wonderful_title.pdf, maintitle=My main title, subtitle=My subtitle]
\chapter{Testing...}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was indeed not the answer I was looking for and probably won't help other StackExchange lurkers if they are in the same situation as me. But indeed, refactoring the problem did help.
However, now I need to find a solution to have boolean values without the need to precise `=true`, the presence of the boolean option means its value is true. Maybe I'm gonna ask another question for that.